# Python RE: Find all matches of pattern b following pattern a

Tags: regex, python-3.x

### I have a text file that looks like this:

1. Warning-[blah1]
2. few lines
3. Warning-[blah2]
4. few more lines
5. Total warnings: 2
6. few more lines
7. Warning-[blah3]
8. more of random lines
9. Warning-[blah4]

---

My objective is to find all matches of Warnings that come after the line "Total warnings: 2".

So far I have tried two approaches:

1. regex = re.compile('Total\s*warnings.*(Warning-[\S+])',re.DOTALL)
2. regex = re.compile('Total\s*warnings.*?(Warning-[\S+])',re.DOTALL)

The first approach gives me the greedy result i.e. matches only blah4 and the second matches only blah3. How can I get it to match both?

I am using findall.

Comment: totally FYI, a nice regex test tool: http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open('sample.txt') as f:
f = f.read()
f = f.split('Total warnings: 2')
f = f[:1]
for el in f:
    el = el.split("\n")
    el = [x for x in el if re.match(r'Warning\-\[.*?\]',x,flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
    print el
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the text file on `"Total warnings"`, and then only processing the second half of the file:

```
import re

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    halves = f.read().split('Total warnings')

regex = re.compile(r'Warning-\[(\S+)\]')
matches = re.findall(regex, halves[1])
```

Comment: It appears that both the responses I have so far require your approach of splitting the data.